What is wrong with saying that a member function can always access the data in the object of which it is a member?
I am wondering about the following multiple-choice question:

A member function can always access the data in __________ , (in C++).

A. the class of which it is member
B. the object of which it is a member
C. the public part of its class
D. the private part of its class


I have been told the answer is A. But I wonder why it can't be B? Why is that not a valid option?

In C++ member functions are members of classes. Saying a member function is a member of an object is just a category error. Membership of objects does not exist in C++.

It's a stupid semantic question.  And the correct answer is "E. The class of which its a member, with exception of private members declared in a base class."

In order to reduce the impression of "Please answer this exam question for which I have only a guessed answer" please desribe your reasons for doubting A as an answer and preferring B.

@selbie Also protected members in some circumstances

class A { int a{}; }; class B : A { void func(); };  The func member function cannot access the a member variable of the object of which the func is a member.

Your answer is correct.  Data exists in an object, not a class.
